# Two Loops in dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, html

The drop down menu only show the first loop with its first item from database and then every items of the first item shown in the first loop. There is no second item listed of the first loop. Any idea to help me with this loop???

```
<ul class="pureCSSMenum">
    <li class="pureCssMenui"><a href="epolicy.php?page=epolicy" target="_self">E-Policy</a>
        <ul class="pureCssMenum">
                    <?
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM e_category";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        while ($epolicy = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {     
                    ?>
                        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><?=$epolicy['e_cat_name']?></a>
                            <ul class="pureCssMenum">
                                <?php
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM e_subcategory";
                                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                                while ($epolicysub = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
                                ?>
                                <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><?=$epolicysub['e_subcat_name']?></a></li>
                                <? } ?>

                            </ul>
                       <? } ?>  

                    </li>
                </ul>    
            </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Should your second query have a WHERE clause instead of retrieving all rows on each loop?

Answer (score 0):

You must use two result variables `$result1, $result2` for outer and inner variable, rest all is fine i think.

Hope this will help

Comment: The second item of the first loop listed, but it also have the same data retrieved from database as the first item of the first loop.

Comment: Ok I got this fixed with the WHERE clause of SQL.. Thank guys